# syntax error near unexpected token done bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to Bash scripting, and I am getting this syntax error near unexpected token `done`. Could anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "starting the process"
while true
do
    echo "Fetching environment variables"
    envsubst < /opt/config.conf.template > /opt/config.conf.prod
    if [ -f /opt/config.conf.prod ] 
    then
    echo "Config file exists."
    python /opt/Deon.py /opt/config.conf.prod
    fi
done
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the exact error message into the question, please? Is there any chance you have Windows or Mac line ends?

Comment: I am building this script in windows notepad ++ and running inside centos. would that impact ?

Comment: If the second line is `do\r`, not `do`, the parser reaches the end of the script without ever seeing the end of the condition. `bash` expects Unix line endings, and failure to use them causes all sorts of problems.

Comment: @sainathpulaparthi Make sure your line endings are appropriate for Linux.  Windows uses `\r\n`, while Linux just uses `\n`.  Notepad++ should have options to change the line endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Windows line endings in your script. Run `dos2unix` on it, and it'll work. As other commenters have said, you'll also want to check that Notepad++ is set to using Unix line endings for Bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "starting the process"
while true; do
    echo "Fetching environment variables"
    envsubst < /opt/config.conf.template > /opt/config.conf.prod
    if [ -f /opt/config.conf.prod ]; then
        echo "Config file exists."
        python /opt/Deon.py /opt/config.conf.prod
    fi
done
```

Not sure if required but I usually put the do on the same line as my condition and put a semicolon between the two (same thing with the if statement). I tried running this this way and it seems to work fine so I'm fairly certain that was the problem, feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This format has the advantage  making more of your script visible for debugging and logic analysis. (IMHO). Upvoting this as it is your first answer and well written and formatted, but note others may downvote because technically another answer with a very different solution has been accepted as solving the original problem (and maybe they are crabby ;-) ).  Good luck to all.

Comment: Ty @shellter, I didn't think about the line endings as I tested the code on a linux machine which I'm guessing is why it worked for me. I'll make sure to take a bit more time to consider things like line endings or encoding problems in the future so this has been a good learning experience ~ Cheers!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info (the section on **Before asking about problematic code**), https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls and https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/newbie_traps for all the gotchas ;-)